# Appending paragraph with parameters and content

Tags: javascript, jquery

This might be a simple answer, but I can't figure it out and jQuery doc's don't help.

I am appending div like this:

```
            $('#container').append(
                $('<p>', {
                    'class': 'myClass',
                    'data-colour': 'green'
                })
            );
```

So what I get is `<p class="myClass" data-colour="green"></p>` and just how can I add text content to this paragraph when appending it?

Comment: *"...and jQuery doc's don't help."* Really? Look at the second example [on the `$`/`jQuery` signature you're using to create the paragraph](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `text` property

```
$('#container').append(
    $('<p />', {
       'class'       : 'myClass',
       'data-colour' : 'green',
       text          : 'Some text'
    })
);
```

Any method available in jQuery for a collection can be used in the object passed when creating an element

```
$('<p />', {
    html : '<span>something</span>',
    css  : {
         color    : 'red',
         fontSize : '15px'
    },
    on   : {
        click : function() {
            alert('clicked');
        },
        mouseenter : function() {

        }
    }
})
```

Comment: And similarly the `html` property if you want to add markup.

Comment: Good call. I was assuming that OP wanted the ability to edit text over time.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** As others have pointed out, you could assign the text inline, when you created the paragraph. If you need the ability to update the text later (multiple times) you could do this:

```
// Store a reference to your new paragraph
var p = $('<p>', {
  'class': 'myClass',
  'data-colour': 'green'
});

// Treat it like you would treat any other jQuery-wrapped element
p.text("Your text goes here...");

// Append it like before
$('#container').append(p);
```

Comment: You don't need a temporary variable. You can just append the `.text()` when the element is created in the original code.

Comment: Yup. I was assuming that OP wanted the ability to edit text over time.